# Move window to screen corners using keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, gnome-shell, window-management

I'm looking for a way to move windows to screen corners (top-left, top, top-right, right, bottom-right, bottom, bottom-left, left, maximize) using keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome Shell 3.28.3).

What I tried that does not work:

- In settings/keyboard shortcuts, there is no way to move window to corners, only to move between screens, workspaces and whatsoever
- the "CompizConfig Settings manager" allows to enable "Grid" and to set keyboard bindings, but they don't have any effect when pressed
- before Ubuntu 18.04, I used quicktile (https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile), but it does not work correctly anymore, also its quite bloated and stuck on Python 2

I would be ok to write a (preferably Python) script to move windows like quicktile does (which high level display library should I use for that nowadays)?

Comment: Asking for a library recommendation is off-topic here, and this question as written is more suitable for [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that "Put windows" https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/ is "enough" to do it, though it seems to be a bit buggy sometimes.
To install it via Chrome, you need to install these packages first:

```
apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions
```

I needed to restart Gnome to make it work.

Comment: however, this doesn't move windows to a second screen. No full happiness in life.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a basic Python script to move windows into screen corners, since all solutions I tried where buggy (gaps between windows and screen corners, windows accidentally moving to other screen), also since this allows to completely customize everything related:

https://github.com/ifischer/window-tiler